# Displaying specific content in modal based on if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display a form in a modal only when two conditions are met. If the conditions are not met, I'm displaying something else. The weird thing here is, if I click the `dev` block first, I can see the `Hello`. However, whenever I click the `social` block first, and go back to clicking the `dev` block after that, the form shows up. What can I do to fix this?

**EDIT**
As suggested by Mark, I reproduced the same behavior felt in my program. Whatever block you click on the information will show regardless of the condition. If you click on the `social` block you should only see the form and when you click on the `dev` block you should only see `Hello.`

Html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click-me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //show modal
    $('.servicemodal').modal('show');

    //get variables
    var socialmediastatus = $(this).attr("socialmediastatus");
    var webstatus = $(this).attr("webstatus");

    //condition
    if (socialmediastatus === 'Not Active' && webstatus === 'social') {

      //show form
      $(".socialmediaform").show();

    } else {
      //append message
      $(".services").append("Hello.");
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.click-me {
  border: lime solid 5px;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 50%;
}


/*to show up*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div webstatus="dev" socialmediastatus="Active" class="click-me">Dev</div>
<div webstatus="social" socialmediastatus="Not Active" class="click-me">Social</div>

<!--Modal -->
<div class="modal fade servicemodal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="services">
          <form style="display:none;" class="socialmediaform" method="POST" action="">
            <input value="" name="first_name" placeholder="please enter your name" class="form-control socialforminput">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using bootstrap modal for this one am I correct?

Comment: I partially put your code in a workable wrapper.  Please put the modal part and the parts represented by `.servicemodal` and the modal and `.socialmediaform` because as it is, this does not fully illustrate your issue.  Also note the `"somediv"` is NOT a valid selector

Comment: @undrftd: Yes I am using bootstrap modal. I will edit with the tags.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Thanks for the edit. I will add more code.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I've reproduced the behavior in the code snippet here. You can try and see for yourself what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you append to your modal, you do not clear it out; and subsequent also appends more text.

Better to either show/hide that or remove the text by placing it in a `span` with a class and remove that. Same basic markup works either way, so I will show/hide to avoid the append challenges hitting the DOM a lot for re-flow.

Note I also move the show/hide modal to last to avoid "flash" in visual that occurs sometimes on some browsers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click-me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //get variables
    var socialmediastatus = $(this).attr("socialmediastatus");
    var webstatus = $(this).attr("webstatus");
    let isSocial = (socialmediastatus === 'Not Active' && webstatus === 'social');
    //show form
    $(".socialmediaform").toggle(isSocial);
    $(".services-text").toggle(!isSocial);
    //show modal
    $('.servicemodal').modal('show');
  });

});
```

```css
.click-me {
  border: lime solid 5px;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 50%;
}


/*to show up*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div webstatus="dev" socialmediastatus="Active" class="click-me">Dev</div>
<div webstatus="social" socialmediastatus="Not Active" class="click-me">Social</div>

<!--Modal -->
<div class="modal fade servicemodal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="services">
          <form style="display:none;" class="socialmediaform" method="POST" action="">
            <input value="" name="first_name" placeholder="please enter your name" class="form-control socialforminput">
          </form>
          <span class="services-text">Howdy!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add the message into a div and show/hide based on condition? like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click-me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //show modal
    $('.servicemodal').modal('show');

    //get variables
    var socialmediastatus = $(this).attr("socialmediastatus");
    var webstatus = $(this).attr("webstatus");

    //condition
    if (socialmediastatus === 'Not Active' && webstatus === 'social') {

      //show form
      $(".socialmediaform").show();
       $(".devContent").hide();

    } else {
      //append message
      $(".devContent").show();
       $(".socialmediaform").hide();
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.click-me {
  border: lime solid 5px;
  margin: 1%;
  width: 50%;
}


/*to show up*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
     
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
<div webstatus="dev" socialmediastatus="Active" class="click-me">Dev</div>
<div webstatus="social" socialmediastatus="Not Active" class="click-me">Social</div>

<!--Modal -->
<div class="modal fade servicemodal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="services">
        <form style="display:none;" class="socialmediaform" method="POST" action="">
        <input value="" name="first_name" placeholder="please enter your name" class="form-control socialforminput">
        </form>
        <div class="devContent" style="display:none;" > Hello. </dev>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function that will clear the form and the appended "Hello" when you dismiss the modal so that it wouldn't show the next time you trigger them.

I've changed your append code into

`$(".services").append("<span class='hellotext'>Hello.</span>");`

Add this additional function for the hidden modal trigger:

`$('.servicemodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(".socialmediaform").hide();
  $(".hellotext").remove();
})`

Your whole code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click-me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //show modal
    $('.servicemodal').modal('show');

    //get variables
    var socialmediastatus = $(this).attr("socialmediastatus");
    var webstatus = $(this).attr("webstatus");

    //condition
    if (socialmediastatus === 'Not Active' && webstatus === 'social') {

      //show form
      $(".socialmediaform").show();

    } else {
      //append message
      $(".services").append("<span class='hellotext'>Hello.</span>");
    }

    $('.servicemodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(".socialmediaform").hide();
        $(".hellotext").remove();
    });

  });
});
```

Check the Bootstrap Documentation as a reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/